# Neo4J query to find same data link to different nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Following is what I created in Neo4j:

Nodes: Customer Names, Customer Address and Customer Contact

Linked these nodes based on common relationships between all three.

I can see all three nodes linked in Neo4j. Contact contain email and phone numbers so some cases customer name node is connected to email address, phone number and address.

In my learning curve I am asked to show how many same contacts are used by different customer names also how many same address used by different customer names. Based on my little experience I tried few queries but couldnt reach to results.

Tried following query -

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[:CONTACT_AT]-()
return distinct n
```

`CONTACT_AT` is the relationship between customer name and Contact (email, phone) node.

Comment: What queries have you tried using?

Comment: might be a wrong query - pardon my lack of knowledge start n=node(*)
match n
where has(n.contact)
return n                             though after running this query it crashes and I reach to crash screen on chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not provide enough information about your data model. To save time, I will assume that it looks something like this (without showing all the properties):

```
(a:Address)<-[:ADDRESS_AT]-(p:Person {name: '...'})-[:CONTACT_AT]->(c:Contact)
```

With this model, this is how you'd get all the names of the people who have the same Contact:

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:CONTACT_AT]->(contact:Contact)
RETURN contact, COLLECT(person.name) AS names;
```

And this is how you'd get all the names of the people who have the same Address:

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:ADDRESS_AT]->(address:Address)
RETURN address, COLLECT(person.name) AS names;
```

Comment: Thanks. Data model is correct. I am struggling to run the cypher query on Chrome web client. It crashes (Aw snaps) after few seconds. I checked it crashes after Chrome RAM uses reaches to 1.2GB. My current system has 72GB of RAM, Windows7, Xeon 2.4 (2 processors).

Comment: I read somewhere that increasing memory in config may help so I tried changing neo4j.properties with following: neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1000M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=1000M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1300M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=1300M but no changes it keep crashing after Chrome uses 1.2GB of RAM

Comment: If you have a large amount of data to be returned, try cutting down the amount. One way to do that is to append `LIMIT 100` to see just 100 result rows.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I tried with LIMIT 100 and 1000 but all addresses have only one node on display. Is it possible to display only the addresses that are linked to more than one customer names? Same for contact it is showing only one to one relationships.